# Proving or disproving regularity of a language

Tags: regular-language, regular-expressions

The question is as follows:

```
 If L1 and L2 are not regular and L1 ⊆ L ⊆ L2, then L is regular
```

My intuition says that it's wrong so I've been looking for a counterexample, so far I didn't succeed.

Can I please get a direction? is this claim might be true?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What about $L_1 = L_2$?

Comment: I don't think I may do that. Besides, even if L1=L2, I can find a language L that is contained in it and regular, so it doesn't disproves the claim.

Comment: If $L_1=L_2$ is not regular, then $L=L_1$ saisfies all conditions, and cannot be regular. If that is not what you need or want, please rephrase the question. You might want to add "for all" or "there exist".

Comment: No, that's probably the counterexample I was looking for, thanks alot :) Can you leave an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take $L_1=L_2$ not regular, then $L=L_1$ satisfies your assumptions, but cannot be regular.